# How to Resize an Array defined as: gcroot<array<double> ^>

Tags: arrays, class, c++-cli, managed

Using Microsoft C++ with `CLR` option. 
I use *gcroot* to define a managed handle to an array in a non-managed class.

See link below for Microsoft *gcroot* example.

```
gcroot < array<double> ^ >  xArray;
```

I then use *gcnew* to allocate the array.

```
myClass.xArray = gcnew array<double>(scanProp.nz);
```

This works and I can use the array as needed by passing to 3rd party library managed functions.

QUESTION: How do I resize the array afterwards?

The `System::Array::Resize` does not accept a *gcroot* array.

I thought about just calling *gcnew* again with the same "Array" variable and let garbage collection release the previous array.

QUESTION:

what happens if *gcnew* is called with the same variable twice?

Is the memory released from the first call?

EXAMPLE:

```
myClass.xArray = gcnew array<double>(100);

myClass.xArray = gcnew array<double>(1000);
```

As shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-declare-handles-in-native-types#see-also

Comment: Unmanaged code having to access a managed array is a pretty heavy code-smell.  But sure, you have to re-assign it since Resize() has to create a new array object.  The GC takes care of cleaning up the spoils, no assistance needed or desired.

Answer (score 3):

Standard warning: While it's certainly possible to write the main body of your application in C++/CLI, or even write the GUI in C++/CLI using WinForms, it is not recommended. C++/CLI is intended for interop scenarios: where C# or other .Net code needs to interface with unmanaged C++, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. Because of that, C++/CLI has all of the complexities of C++, all of the complexities of C#, and some complexities of its own. For primary development, it is recommended to use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

---

First, there's no such thing as a true "resize" of a .Net array. .Net arrays, by definition, have one size which is fixed at creation time. The `Array::Resize` method is actually creating a new array with the needed size, and copying all your data from the old array to the new array.

It's not letting you call `Array::Resize` with the `gcroot` because `Resize` takes a tracking reference parameter (`ref` in C#, `^%` in C++/CLI).

You could take the `gcroot`, copy it to a local (non-gcroot) variable, call `Array::Resize` on that, then re-assign that to the `gcroot`.

```
gcroot<array<double>^> xArray;

int newsize = ...;

array<double>^ temp = xArray;
Array::Resize(temp, newsize);
xArray = temp;
```

However, there's nothing special that [`Array::Resize`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/array.cs.html#71074deaf111c4e3) is doing, you can do it yourself.

```
gcroot<array<double>^> xArray;

int newsize = ...;

array<double>^ newArray = gcnew array<double>(newsize);
Array::Copy(xArray, 0, newArray, 0, Math::Min(xArray->Length, newsize));
xArray = newArray;
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you !  Note that I am using C++ with MFC, and a managed graphics library, with a C++ API interface.